# How to properly log out the user under the condition that both HTTP and Ajax calls are possible

Tags: php, ajax

I have a page in which certain HTTP and Ajax requests are made. As obvious, if the user is not authenticated for any reason whatsoever, I need to log him out. This following block is the server side process for logging out the user:

```
if (!$logged || !safetyRules()) {
    KillTheSession();
    leaveFor('login.php');
    exit();
}
```

This works fine with the HTTP request, as clear. The moment user is not authenticated, the page kills the session, and leaves for the login page. But when the request is Ajax, the session is killed in case of improper authentication, but the page is not redirected to the login page, simply as it is an Ajax request.

I have tried to add a line so that I can get the value with JavaScript or Jquery and redirect the user to the login page. I have added this line before redirecting.

```
echo json_encode(['NOT_AUTHENTICATED' => true], JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR);
```

But the problem is when the php gets to the part where it needs to redirect to the login page, it does not echo out the this value.

I have thought of authenticating based on the request type, and as per that condition redirect the page in case we have an HTTP request, or just kill the session in case the request is Ajax. The scenario would be:

```
if (!$logged || !safetyRules()) {
    KillTheSession();
    if (ajaxCertified()) {
        echo json_encode(['NOT_AUTHENTICATED' => true], JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR);
    } else {
        leaveFor('login.php');
    }
    exit();
}
```

But as I guess Ajax authentications are easy to bypass, I am a bit worried about the security issues.
In this scenario what is the best php practice to properly logout the user under condition that both HTTP and Ajax requests are possible?

Comment: An Ajax request is a HTTP request. It just does not reload the browser page. It is no more secure or insecure as any other request. Have your app popup a login. Login in through "ajax" and go on with the rest o the transaction. With ajax your basically working with data vs a presentation page.